# Camel Rest DSL Removing another extra Route

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am building a rest route on camel based on rest DSL. For example, based on the configuration, the rest route uses a direct component.

**Rest Route**

```
rest("resturi")
.post()
.to(direct:inbox);
```

> resturi is dynamic

```
from(direct:inbox)
.process(camelprocessor)
.to(queue);
```

**Is there any way we can remove the direct component and combine into one route.**

I appreciate any advice regarding the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by adding **.route()**

`.post().route().process(camelprocessor).to(queue);`

But think from the feature reusable perspective, direct component will be the best choice.

Comment: But when i use the rest("resturi") that route gets called 2 times even when i hit the URL with the by attaching a message body only once using postman.... Any way to resolve this issue !

Answer (score 1):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_camel_development_guide/restservices-restdsl

XML dsl example

```
  <get uri="/some">
     <route>
       <setBody>
         <constant>HW!</constant>
       </setBody>
     </route>   
</get>
```

You can call your processor in this route.